# IBM MQ ignores JMS ExceptionListener registered by Camel + Spring Boot based app

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

We develop a microservice based on Apache Camel JMS component and Spring Boot. IBM MQ is used as messaging middleware. There is an issue with exception listener - IBM MQ classes can't find registered exception listener and print it's own stack trace in system out when connection with MQ is broken:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsProviderExceptionListener
The exception is ignored as no exception listener is registered: '
                   Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
An error has occurred with the IBM MQ JMS connection.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
```

`org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory` is used for connection setup.

```
@Bean
protected final ConnectionFactory createMqJmsConnectionFactory() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    // Factory setup
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(mqFactory);    

    return cachingFactory;
}
```

`CachingConnectionFactory`'s ancestor implementes `javax.jms.ExceptionListener` and, as I found on Spring forum, registers itself as exceptionListener. From stack trace I can see that `onException()` method is invoked after exception, resets connection and writes log.

So we have a situation when IBM MQ ignores `CachingConnectionFactory` as exception listener. Camel JMS component has `exceptionListener` endpoint configuration option - I assume, adding of the `CachingConnectionFactory` here would be redundantly.

Any other settings need to be done in order to register `CachingConnectionFactory` as exception listener?

Comment: Try adding `exceptionListener` in endpoint configuration, even if it appears to be redundant. Or add the object itself as `exceptionListener` in the above `@Bean` definition by calling `cachingFactory.setExceptionListener(cachingFactory)`. It may seem redundant based on what you read on spring forums, but trying that will make sure that your `ExceptionListener` is actually set and is not an assumption.